# Angular 2/4 - How to access specific array in ngFor

Tags: angular

I've got an array of items in which I'm comparing a user id of the current element vs the previous one. When I try this code, it results in a blank page with no errors:

```
<ion-item *ngFor="let message of messages; let i = index;">
   <div *ngIf="message.user_id !== messages[i-1].user_id"></div>
</ion-item>
```

Can you not access array indexes in the template this way?

Comment: This example will probably fail for index `[0]` because `[i-1]` will be `[-1]` which doesn't exist

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`0-1 === -1` so skip the first item.

```
<ion-item *ngFor="let message of messages; let i = index; let isFirst = first">
   <div *ngIf="!isFirst && message.user_id !== messages[i-1].user_id"></div>
</ion-item>
```